# When will fglrx work on latest Xorg server 1.9?

Tags: 10.10, xorg, ati, fglrx

As many laptops with an ATI Radeon (5470HD) in it, mine is having issues too when installing the proprietary driver fglrx (screen hangs on startup). I read somewhere that these issues appear because the latest fglrx driver doesn't support the latest Xorg server 1.9 yet, which is installed on Ubuntu 10.10.

So my question is whether any of you know when ati will support the latest xorg server?

Answer (score 3):

The version of fglrx found in Ubuntu 10.10 *does* support Xserver 1.9, the version of the X server in Ubuntu 10.10.  Your problem is due to something else.

Comment: Oh harsh, you know what might be the problem then? :s